# jQuery Ajax call success then re-direct

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, redirect, if-statement

**SOLVED** - will add own answer and mark as solved.

On an Ajax/JSON call that is successful **AND** where a jQuery variable has a certain value - is it possible to re-direct to another page?

For example [*code snippet only - not full code, to save space*]:

```
if(json.response.status == 'success') {
                    if($page == 'ten'){
                        window.location.replace("finish.php");
                    }else{
                        $('.sequence-container div').hide().delay( 2000 );
                        $next.show().delay( 2000 );
                    }

                }
```

The above code is saving to the DB correctly but when it does **and** `$page == 'ten'` it doesn't do the redirect.

I have a feeling I've got how Ajax works incorrectly but could use some feedback if possible.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you put any alert and tested inside the if condition?  like `if($page == 'ten'){alert('came to if ...')}`

Comment: So `$page` does not equal `ten`.

Comment: Alert does show $page = 'ten'.

Comment: Check the console for errors

Comment: I have tried and it does redirect as required when `$page='ten'`. Is it entering the if condition? Are there any leading/trailing spaces in the value?

Comment: Odd, although $page = 'ten' the re-direct doesn't work but if I add another `div` called 'eleven', which is blank - the re-direct works.  Clearly something in my `next/previous` code is causing an issue.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst `$page = 'ten'` without a further `div` on my page, the code won't fire.  For simplicity and due to time constraints, I have added the div and will review the '$page' to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if(json.response.status == 'success') {
                if($page == 'ten'){
                    window.location.href="finish.php";
                }else{
                    $('.sequence-container div').hide().delay( 2000 );
                    $next.show().delay( 2000 );
                }

            }
```

It should work. Works for me :)

Comment: Thanks for replying but no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use complete URL like: http://yourdomain.com/finish.php , e.g.

```
if(json.response.status == 'success')
{
    if($page == 'ten')
    {
        window.location.replace("http://yourdomain.com/finish.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $('.sequence-container div').hide().delay( 2000 );
        $next.show().delay( 2000 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, not making any difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(json.response.status == 'success') {
                if($page == 'ten'){
                    window.location = "./finish.php"
                }else{
                    $('.sequence-container div').hide().delay( 2000 );
                    $next.show().delay( 2000 );
                }

            }
```

You can use this aswell.